# XPATH - Correct?

Tags: xpath

I am using the following xpath to get the sections outlined as in the image below ( http://advrider.com/forums/ ), but am not being to. Is there something wrong with it?

```
//TABLE/TBODY/TR[@class='dg-forums-level2 dg-align-center']/TD[2]/DIV[1]/A[1]
```

[image]

**Updated**

```
<?php
$BASE_PATH = "../src/";

include_once($BASE_PATH  . "classes/forumdb.php");
include_once($BASE_PATH  . "classes/curl.php");

$curl = new curl();
$html = $curl->get_web_page('http://advrider.com/forums/');

$doc = new DOMDocument();
$doc->loadHTML($html);

$xpath = new DOMXpath($doc);

//$elements = $xpath->query("//TABLE[@class='tborder']/TBODY/TR[@class='']/TD[2]/DIV[1]/A[1]/STRONG[1]");

$elements = $xpath->query("//*[@id='f3']"); //works
//$elements = $xpath->query("//TABLE/TBODY/TR");


//TD[@id='f74']/DIV[1]/A[1]

if (!is_null($elements))
{

  foreach ($elements as $element)
  {
    echo "f<br/>[". $element->nodeName. "]";
    $nodes = $element->childNodes;
    foreach ($nodes as $node)
    {
      echo $node->nodeValue. "\n";
    }
  }
}

?>
```

Comment: Your XPath is good and it works for me well on FF11 and FireFinder. Which tool are you using to retrieve the elements? Do you see any sort of error? If you're using IE, you should write the tag names in lower-case.

Comment: @slanec - i am using php, i will put up the code now, nice if you can take a look.

Comment: @slanec - one more thing, how i check in ff11 ?

Comment: [Firebug](http://getfirebug.com/) plus [Firefinder](https://addons.mozilla.org/en-US/firefox/addon/firefinder-for-firebug/)

Comment: No idea about this one, mate.

Comment: To specify an XPath expression that selects the wanted nodes, we need two things: 1. The XML document containing the nodes of interest; 2. Some kind of identification of the nodes of interest -- a picture isn't the same as unique identification. You havent provided either -- therefore it is meaningless based only on this information to provide an answer. Please, edit the question and provide the necessary, important information.

Comment: @Dimitre Novatchev - thats why i gave the link in the question above

Comment: I don't know php, but I'm confused with the updated code. There are no elements with id=f3. Where is your initial xpath in this code? What does all this commented xpaths mean?

Comment: Imran: The resource identified by that link isn't well-formed XML. Thus one cannot evaluate an XPath expression on it. You may try to use one of several available tools like the "HTML Agility Pack" that provide capability resempling those of an XPath engine -- but over HTML

Comment: @Dimitre Novatchev - I am able to evaluate it properly using javascript. But do not know how to do it php

Comment: very good link when using xpaths http://test-able.blogspot.ie/2016/04/xpath-selectors-cheat-sheet.html

Answer (score 1):

```
//li[div[@class='nodeInfo categoryNodeInfo categoryStrip' and div/h3/a[text()='Riding']]]//div[@class='nodeText']/h3[@class='nodeTitle']
```

Use it and try to avoid places like TD[2]/DIV[1]/A[1].
Selectors with classes are less brittle than selectors with numeric position in DOM tree.

I hope that it'll help

Answer (score 1):

I would use this:

```
//*[@class="nodeTitle"]/a
```

**<kbd>[`demo`](http://xpatheval.apphb.com/O47p8vwUn)</kbd>**

Answer (score 0):

You can try the below xpath:

`//ol[@class='nodeList']//*[@class='nodeTitle']//a`

It will find the all the sections in the page.

Answer (score -1):

To grap the section details text or url ,pls use these below xpath

```
//h3[@class="nodeTitle"]/a[@data-description]/text() #To grap text
//h3[@class="nodeTitle"]/a[@data-description]/@href #To grap url
```